# System Administrator profile don't have the permission but they can still see LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, permissions, system-admin

I have created a custom LWC component and custom permission. The logic is that only users with the custom permission set I created should see the component on the page.
The issue is that it works as supposed for all profiles except System Administrator profile.
Even if users with System Administrator profile don't have the permission assigned to them - they can still see my component.
How can I fix this?

I used custom permission in the LWC:

```
import hasPermission from '@salesforce/customPermission/CustomPerm';
connectedCallback() {
   this.canAccess = hasPermission;
 }
```

and use it in html:

```
<template>
  <template if:true={canAccess}>
    .....
  </template>
</template>
```

However, System Administrator can see this lwc.

Comment: can you double-check, that this custom permission is not assigned to the `System Administrator` profile?  Custom Permissions may be assigned both to profiles and permission sets.

Comment: @Oleksandr Berehovskyi
 I'm sure